# multiple lines in a link should act simultaniously on hover but they don't

Tags: css, hover

I have a link that covers a couple of lines of HTML and on hover they should all change color (or whatever) but they only react per line.

If I use JSfiddle and paste the code, it works, but in my wordpress site it doesn't work anymore...

http://jsfiddle.net/6QgAR/

HTML

```
<div id="homelink"><a href="http://www.google.com"><p style="text-align: center;">    <em>Lorum Ipsum</em><br>
Lorum Ipsum</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorum Ipsum</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorum Ipsum<br>
Lorum Ipsum</p>
</a></div>
```

CSS

```
#homelink:hover a{
    color:#ff6600;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

live: http://goo.gl/xU0iFz

Any idea how this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome. On your live site

Comment: I don't think you should have a paragraph (<p>) tag inside you link tag.

Comment: Yeah, the P-tags, is a wordpress thing. It doesn't accept <br /><br />. I simply turns it into <p>. I now removed the HTML and used plain text and hacked some more with the custom-fields (for doing styling).

Answer (score 0):

There are other stylesheets on your live site which you aren't including in the jsfiddle. There is some styling for p level elements, so if you want it to work to override it then you'll need to do:

```
#homelink:hover a p {
color:#ff6600;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

However, you really shouldn't have block level elements within the a tag. You could change the ps to spans and then just define them as block elements in the css so that you would be semantically correct, or  why  not just remove the a element all together and link from the div?, e.g.

```
<div id="homelink" onclick="window.location='http://google.com';">
  <p><em>Lorum Ipsum</em><br>
    Lorum Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorum Ipsum</p>
   <p>Lorum Ipsum<br>
    Lorum Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

And keep your styling in the css sheet, e.g.:

```
 #homelink p { text-align: center }
 #homelink:hover { color:#ff6600; text-decoration:none; }
```

Comment: thanks for this answer!
It's worpdress who makes the ps by itself. I hacked a little around it, and now it seems to work

ps. I wanted to vote up your answer, but I haven't got 15 reputation yet :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by working around it.
I have no idea why it worked in JSfiddle, and not on the wordpress site (but that is more often the case with wordpress ;).

I changed the WYSIWYG editor into plain text, and therefor the

tags didn't come back automatically, and that solved the problem.